# Получение значений из объекта при неизвестных ключах

Tags: javascript

Есть json объект (элементов может быть больше):

```
[
  {
    '614303455': {
      id: '614303455',
      status: 'passed',
      duration: 2.11,
      retries: 0,
      title: null,
      suite: 'Позитивные'
    }
  },
  {
    '51435655': {
      id: '51435655',
      status: 'passed',
      duration: 1.22,
      retries: 0,
      title: null,
      suite: 'Позитивные'
    }
  }
]
```

Нужно достать все значения поля `duration`

Но из-за того что путь до `duration` выглядит так: `obj.'51435655'.duration`, у меня трудности именно с перебором 614303455/51435655, т.к. так могут быть любые цифры

Comment: Так а где ваш код с трудностями?

Comment: Попробуйте [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: вышло вот так, но мне кажется есть вариант попроще

   obj.forEach((item) => {
       Object.values(item).forEach(item2 => {
           console.log(item2.duration)
       })
   })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обойтись без знания значений ключей 614303455/51435655 можно, например, с помощью метода [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

В остальном же всё равно надо пройтись по "внешнему массиву" и по массивам values внутри, так что попроще (чем вариант в комментариях к вопросу) особо не выйдет

Можно сложить значения `duration` в массив и выводить на экран его. Это пригодится, если нужно как-то работать с `duration` дальше по коду

```js
var data = [
  {
    '614303455': {
      id: '614303455',
      status: 'passed',
      duration: 2.11,
      retries: 0,
      title: null,
      suite: 'Позитивные'
    }
  },
  {
    '51435655': {
      id: '51435655',
      status: 'passed',
      duration: 1.22,
      retries: 0,
      title: null,
      suite: 'Позитивные'
    }
  }
];

var durations = data.flatMap(obj => Object.values(obj))
                    .map(value => value.duration);
console.log(durations);
```